# How to run a python function or script somescript.py on the KubernetesPodOperator in airflow?

Tags: kubernetes, airflow

I am running a Celery Executor and I'm trying to run some python script in the KubernetesPodOperator. Below are examples of what I have tried that didn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Running sctipt

```
org_node = KubernetesPodOperator(
    namespace='default',
    image="python",
    cmds=["python", "somescript.py" "-c"],
    arguments=["print('HELLO')"],
    labels={"foo": "bar"},
    image_pull_policy="Always",
    name=task,
    task_id=task,
    is_delete_operator_pod=False,
    get_logs=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

Running function `load_users_into_table()`

```
def load_users_into_table(postgres_hook, schema, path):
  gdf = read_csv(path)
  gdf.to_sql('users', con=postgres_hook.get_sqlalchemy_engine(), schema=schema)

org_node = KubernetesPodOperator(
    namespace='default',
    image="python",
    cmds=["python", "somescript.py" "-c"],
    arguments=[load_users_into_table],
    labels={"foo": "bar"},
    image_pull_policy="Always",
    name=task,
    task_id=task,
    is_delete_operator_pod=False,
    get_logs=True,
    dag=dag
)
```

Comment: What do you mean exactly didn't work?

Comment: Do you configure [KubernetesExecutor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/executor/kubernetes.html)?

Comment: i am running a Celery Executor .The operator does not recognize the file (file not found) and when i try to pass the function it also does not work

Answer (score 3):

The script `somescript.py` must be in `Docker image`.

**Step-1**: let's create a image https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/.

```
FROM python:3.8

# copy requirement.txt from local to container
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
# install dependencies into container (geopandas, sqlalchemy)
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# copy the python script from local to container
COPY somescript.py somescript.py
ENTRYPOINT [ "python", "somescript.py"]
```

**Step-2**: Build and push the image into `public Docker repository` https://hub.docker.com.

*NB:* `kubernetes_pod_operator` looks for image from `public docker repo`

```
# build image
docker build -t my-python-img:latest .
# test if your image works perfectly
docker run my-python-img:latest

# push image.
docker tag my-python-img username/my-python-img
docker push username/my-python-img
docker pull username/my-python-img
```

**step-3:** Lest's create `k8s task`.

```
p = KubernetesPodOperator(
        namespace='default',
        image='username/my-python-img:latest',
        labels={'dag-id': dag.dag_id},
        name='airflow-my-image-pod',
        task_id='load-users',
        in_cluster=False,       #False: local, True: cluster               
        cluster_context='microk8s',  
        config_file='/usr/local/airflow/include/.kube/config',
        is_delete_operator_pod=True,
        get_logs=True,
        dag=dag
    )
```

If you don't understand where configuration file comes from, look here: https://www.astronomer.io/docs/cloud/stable/develop/kubepodoperator-local.

**Finally:** I want to mention something important when working with databases (credentials). Kubernetes offers the use `secret` to secure sensitive information. https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/operators.html

Answer (score 2):

[KubernetesPodOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow-providers-cncf-kubernetes/stable/operators.html#how-does-this-operator-work) launches a Kubernetes pod that runs a container as specified in the operator's arguments.

### First Example

In the first example, the following happens:

- KubernetesPodOperator instructs K8s to lunch a pod and prepare to run a container in it using [the python image](https://hub.docker.com/_/python?tab=tags&page=1&ordering=last_updated&name=latest) (the `image` parameter) from hub.docker.com (the default image registry)
- [ENTRYPOINT](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#entrypoint) of the python image is replaced by `["python", "somescript.py" "-c"]` (the `cmd` parameter)
- [CMD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) of the python image is replaced by `["print('HELLO')"]` (the `arguments` parameter)
- ...
- The container is run

So, the complete command that is run in the container is

```
python somescript.py -c print('HELLO')
```

Obviously, the official Python image from Docker Hub does not have `somescript.py` in its working directory. Even if did, it probably would have been not the one that you wrote. That is why the command fails with something like:

```
python: can't open file 'somescrit.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

### Second Example

In the second example, pretty much the same happens as in the first example, but the command that is run in the container (again based on the `cmd` and `arguments` parameters) is

```
python somescript.py -c None
```

(`None` is the string representation of the `load_users_into_table()`'s return value)

This command fails, because of the same reasons as in the first example.

### How It Could be Done (a Sketch)

You could build a Docker image with `somescript.py` and all its dependencies. Push the image to an image registry. Specify the image, ENTRYPOINT, and CMD in the corresponding parameters of KubernetesPodOperator.

Comment: Would it be possible to pass a volume to the public image for adding our script? Or the only option is to create a custom image?

Comment: @JavierLopezTomas I believe it should be possible.